# Distribution of a sum of almost-Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let's say I have a random variable X is the following:

- support of $X$ is in $[0; a]$, where $a > 0$
- $P(X = 0) = p$
- otherwise the distribution of X is continuous, i.e. $P(X = x) = 0$ for $x > 0$

I am interested in computing the distribution of $S$, the sum of $n$ independent variables that follow the distribution of $X$.

Especially, I'm interested in computing the 10% - 90% quantiles of this distribution. Is there anyway to get this value without doing numerical simulation of S and checking its quantiles?

Thanks !

Comment: what is the distribution of $X$ on $(0, a]$? uniform?

Comment: @ironX could be anything

Comment: The central limit theorem applies. Is $p$ especially close to $1$ or to $0$?

Comment: @kimchilover good point ! Here p is small (I'd say 0.001) and n is large (few millions)

Comment: So most of the time your summand is from the distribution you don't know about?  Your $S$ is the sum of a few multiples of $999,000$ of a continuous random variable supported in $[0,a]$, whose mean and variance could be most any numbers in $(0,a]$ and $(0,a^2/4]$.  No can solve, given the data supplied.

Comment: @kimchilover it's not that I 'don't know' about the distribution, but rather that I know it numerically and want to find a solution different than explicitly computing the S distribution and extracting the quantiles from it

Comment: Most useful would be the mean and variance for the summand distribution.  Then  the CLT would give a usable approximation to your quantiles.